# prevent direct access to php file used as an image

Tags: php

Here's an interesting one, I am trying to prevent direct access to PHP file.

Usually, I would define a variable in the top level file and the included file would check if it's set to prevent it.

However, this particular PHP file is included as an image, as in:

```
<img src="/includes/youtube_image_proxy.php?id=12" />
```

So, the normal way doesn't actually work, is there a way around this?

Comment: The browser **has** to directly access it in order to get the image. Why do you want to prevent access to it? It might be possible to achieve your real goal if you explain that.

Comment: HTTP has no notion of "direct access", it's mostly stateless. Common workarounds include Referer checks or session cookie states (both whacky and unreliable). You should have a more solid reason than hypothetical external references.

Comment: Implementing a check via the session would be the easiest way, but requires that the user accepts the session cookie. (Unless you wanted to append the session ID as a GET parameter to the image URLs, but that is usually not recommendable for security reasons.) Another way would be to pass a timestamp value along, and then only allow the request if that timestamp isn’t older than x minutes or something. Send along a hash of that timestamp and a secret value only you know, to avoid manipulation. […]

Comment: […]  Of course this would break things, if the user for example saved the HTML code of the page, and then tried to view it again later - the images would not load then, because the timestamp is too old.

Comment: Just Why? Why would you want to show an image in a page, but then not let the user get to it separately?

Comment: It's a proxy to get a file, otherwise it loads a normal image if we have it.

Answer (score 0):

use    $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]    to see if the file is being called from your website

like if `<img src="/includes/youtube_image_proxy.php?id=12" />` is on `yourwebsite.com/link/file.html`, the referer will be `yourwebsite.com`

in case i take the same image file and put it on my `website.com/link/filebeta.html` it wont work since you are testing on the referer

Comment: That can be spoofed easily enough: http://thisinterestsme.com/php-spoof-http-referer-field/